# Unable to route after installing Umbraco with MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have recently installed `Umbraco` CMS over on my existing sites. Things seems fine as far as installation is concerned.

But the issue is I am now unable to browse my existing website. My defined routes in `RouteConfig.cs` are not hit, instead routes are picked from somewhere else.

Can anybody help me with this? From where routing is being currently and how can I configured it to use my existing routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Umbraco, you can put custom MVC routes in a class that inherits from the `IApplicationEventHandler`.

Using this example code from [shazwazza.com](http://shazwazza.com/post/Custom-MVC-routing-in-Umbraco):

```
public class MyStartupHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationStarted(
        UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, 
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        //Create a custom route
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "test",
            "Products/{action}/{id}",
            new
                {
                    controller = "MyProduct", 
                    action = "Product", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                });           
    }

    public void OnApplicationInitialized(
    UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, 
    ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarting(
        UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, 
        ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

This code overrides the `ApplicationStarted` method. From here, you can add your custom routing logic, which will be picked up by Umbraco during it's booting sequence.